# Explanation of the term "view" for algorithm or adversary

Tags: terminology, security-definition, adversarial-model

What is the view of an algorithm/adversary? Is view just a term used to describe the output over a set of inputs for a probabilistic algorithm?

For example:

> Consider experiment Mac-forgeA,Π (n). In that experiment, the view of
>   A when run as a subroutine by A is distributed identically to its view
>   in experiment Mac-forge A',Π' (n).

Also, I've always assumed an identical distribution is one that is literally identical to the original distribution. I just had the thought that it may be a distribution that is output with identical probability as the original distribution. Are either of these guesses correct?

Comment: The view of an interactive machine is the random variable of its random tape and received messages.

Comment: Sorry, its random tape, *input*, and received messages. Notice that the view completely determines the sent messages and output.

Comment: If I were to use message authentication as an example, would the random tape be the a messages the adversary wants to generate an authentication tag for? And the input would be the oracle the adversary has access to?

Comment: Are you sure that the original was "the view of A when run as a subroutine by A" - that sounds odd to me, my guess would be the original is "when run as a subroutine by some reduction R" or something like that.

Comment: @xtt has a quine mccluskey!

Comment: @EdwardR.Murrow I might be missing something – who is xtt?

Comment: @e-sushi The [person](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/42821/xtt) who posted this bounty

Comment: @EdwardR.Murrow Gosh, indeed I missed that. Thanks for the heads-up!